# Beta on the site logo

Tags: discussion, design

I noticed that the site still has a Beta tag. Is that correct? I thought the participation meant that this was now a valid SE site.

Should this be removed and it just be "Writers?"

Answer (score 6):

Sites are in "beta" until they "graduate" as a full site: [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

The site is open to the public but it is still in beta (i.e. only the first 7 days are private). The site will remain in beta at least 90 days, after which we will start looking at the [performance statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers) to determine when the site will get its own design and graduate as a full (non-beta) site.

Comment: That's a much better answer then mine.

Answer (score 2):

We are still in Beta, just an public beta as opposed to the private beta we started with. It will take at least another 70 days or so before we can be officially launched, longer if they don't think we're ready.